# Accuracy of BufferedImage.getRGB()

Tags: java, image-processing, rgb, bufferedimage

I've coded up a program that can read rgb values off of a jpg file, but when i test it with a solid color i'm getting rgb results that are slightly inaccurate. Does anyone know if its my code or if its java that is inaccurate?

**RGB**

[red=64 green=0 blue=128](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3fvb.jpg)

**RESULT**

[red=65 green=0 blue=128](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbcOV.png)

**CODE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.*;


public class Program {
    public int[][] rgbValues;
    public File imagePath = new File("src/image3.jpg");
    public BufferedImage image;

    public Program() throws IOException{
        image = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
        rgbValues = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
    }
    public void run() throws IOException{
        getData();
        analyzeData();

    }
    private void getData() throws IOException{      
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
                rgbValues[y][x] = image.getRGB(x, y);
            }

        }
    }
    private void analyzeData() throws IOException{
        boolean f = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;
        Color color = new Color(rgbValues[10][10], f);
        System.out.println(color.getRed());
        System.out.println(color.getGreen());
        System.out.println(color.getBlue());

    }

}
```

Comment: IrfanView and GIMP agree that the color is indeed (**65**, 0, 128) in the image that you linked.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe jpeg compression messes with the rbg.

Comment: Maybe provide some more information about how you created and stored the image....?!

Comment: I used ms paint and selected a color by typing in rgb values. I saved it as a jpg file.

Comment: I think its due to the jpg compression.

Comment: You could, to some extent, verify this by saving it as PNG, or by changing the *quality* of the JPG file. (I'm a bit surprised that JPG should change the whole color for a single-colored image, but maybe this can be explained with a deeper knowledge of the JPG compression method...)

Comment: The change would probably wouldn't be noticed by the naked eye, because the red value was increased by an increment of 1. Apparently JPG image files are compressed through a lossy compression method which leads to slight degradation in color and tone. [source](http://oreilly.com/catalog/webphoto/chapter/ch06.html)

Comment: It's well-known that JPG is lossy and a high compression will cause artifacts - but this usually happens at sharp corners and edges. I would not have expected a change in an image that only consist of a single color.

Comment: @Marco13, nullPointerException: It's possible that such minor errors are introduced by small rounding errors in the RGB -> YCbCr -> RGB roundtrip (JPEG is usually stored as subsampled YCbCr samples).

Answer (score 0):

Code seems correct and results as well, Paint says the image is also (65,0,128)